# Facing Issue while implementing internationalization in Spring Boot Mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

While accessing the url I am getting following exception.

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:193)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:178)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:145)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
Root Cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy
org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.setLocale(AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.java:142)
org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor.preHandle(LocaleChangeInterceptor.java:154)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:141)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1035)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:193)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:178)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:145)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)

**My Configuration Class looks as below :**

```
package com.spring.mvc.messenger.config;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
public class MessengerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/pdf/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(getLocaleChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor getLocaleChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setOrder(0);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

}
```

**My message.properties file have following details:**

```
#labels
name=Name

#button
save.changes=Save Changes
```

**My message_es.properties file have following details:**

```
#labels
name=Nombre   

#button
save.changes=Guardar cambios
```

**My Jsp files is**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome Home Jsp</h1>
    <spring:message code="name" />
</body>
</html>
```

**My Controller Class**

```
package com.spring.mvc.messenger.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MessengerController {

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView getHomePage(Model model) {
        return new ModelAndView("WelcomeHome");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/home")
    public ModelAndView homePage(Model model) {
        return new ModelAndView("WelcomeHome");
    }

}
```

**My ApplicationClass is**

```
package com.spring.mvc.messenger;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MessengerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessengerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Can anyone help me out with this..  I have tried using different locale . But still similar response is getting**

Comment: rename `getLocaleResolver` to `localeResolver`. The `LocaleResolver` is detected by name not by type. Also remove the `ViewResolver` and add `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` to your `application.properties`.

Comment: Yeah, It worked for me .. thanks @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes error can be about not adding annotation "@EnableWebMvc"